# NSRegularExpression ISSUE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, twitter, hashtag

I'm working with NSRegularExpression to read a text and find out hashtag.
This is NSString that I used in regularExpressionWithPattern.

```
- (NSString *)hashtagRegex
{
    return @"#((?:[A-Za-z0-9-_]*))";
    //return @"#{1}([A-Za-z0-9-_]{2,})";

}
```

And this is my method:

```
 // Handle Twitter Hashtags
  detector = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[self hashtagRegex] options:0 error:&error];
  links = [detector matchesInString:theText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, theText.length)];
  current = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:links];

    NSString *hashtagURL =   @"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23";
  //hashtagURL = [hashtagURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

  for ( int i = 0; i < [links count]; i++ ) {

    NSTextCheckingResult *cr = [current objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *url = [theText substringWithRange:cr.range];

    NSString *nohashURL = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
    nohashURL = [nohashURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    [theText replaceOccurrencesOfString:url 
                             withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@%@\">%@</a>", hashtagURL, nohashURL, url]
                                options:NSLiteralSearch 
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, theText.length)];
    current = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[detector matchesInString:theText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, theText.length)]];

  }

  [theText replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br />" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, theText.length)];

  [_aWebView loadHTMLString:[self embedHTMLWithFontName:[self fontName] 
                                                   size:[self fontSize] 
                                                   text:theText]
                    baseURL:nil];
```

Everything worked but it figured out a little issue when I use a string like this:

```
NSString * theText = @"#twitter #twitterapp #twittertag";
```

My code highlights only #twitter on each word and not the second part of it (#twitter #twitter(app) #twitter(tag)).
I hope someone will help me!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
[theText replaceOccurrencesOfString:url 
                         withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@%@\">%@</a>", hashtagURL, nohashURL, url]
                            options:NSLiteralSearch 
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, theText.length)];
```

is replacing *all* instances of the string `url` with the replacement string. In the example you give, the first time through the loop, `url` is `@"#twitter"`, and all three occurrences of that string within `theText` are replaced in one go. This is what `theText` looks like then:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23twitter">#twitter</a> <a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23twitter">#twitter</a>app <a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23twitter">#twitter</a>tag
```

So, of course, the next two times round the loop, the results are not quite what you expect...  !

I think the fix is to limit the range of the replacement:

```
[theText replaceOccurrencesOfString:url 
                         withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@%@\">%@</a>", hashtagURL, nohashURL, url]
                            options:NSLiteralSearch 
                              range:cr.range];
```

Comment: You're right!I was completely absent-minded,I didn't notice that..thank-you It works like a charm!!